# Does ASP.net identity uses open id connect?

Tags: asp.net-identity, google-openid

I want to use OpenID for my authentication. Does ASP.net identity uses [google open id connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)? because google says:

> Important: Google has deprecated OpenID 2.0 and will shut it down
>   after a migration period. If your app uses OpenID 2.0, you must
>   migrate your app by the shutdown date April 20, 2015, as shown in the
>   migration timetable.

Comment: You can use HovaID, It's new and a fresh version of it will comes out in Jun 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can use both:

> Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google - Contains middlewares to support Google's OpenId and OAuth 2.0 authentication workflows.

[Source](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Packages&referringTitle=Home).